# Vue, active router-link not updating after first change

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a strange issue which I struggled with for a long time... I have a Sidebar with several router-links.

```
<template>
  <div class="nav nav-pills main-nav" id="sidebar" role="tablist">
    <router-link class="nav-link" to="/tasks">
      Tasks
    </router-link>
    <router-link class="nav-link" to="/notes">
      Notes
    </router-link>
    <router-link class="nav-link" to="/sounds">
      Sounds
    </router-link>
    <div class="account">
      <router-link class="nav-link" to="/profile">
        Profile
      </router-link>
      <a class="nav-link" @click="logOut">
        Log out
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "sidebar",
  methods: {
    ...
  }
};
</script>
```

I have a strange issue with the behaviour of the latter menu. If I go to localhost:8080/notes, the notes button is active as expected. Then, if I click on any of the other link(let's say /tasks), it becomes active as expected. However, if I click on some link once again, /tasks remains active and the new page does not become active. That is, I will be able to navigate to other pages, but the /tasks router link will be active whatever I do. In other words, the "active" link is only updated once... I have no idea what the problem might be :/ Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

In App.vue I import the sidebar

```
  <div id="app">
    <router-view name="header"></router-view>
    <router-view name="sidebar"></router-view>
    <main :class="{ 'remove-width': sidebarOpened }">
      <fade-transition origin="center" mode="out-in" :duration="250">
        <router-view />
      </fade-transition>
    </main>
  </div>
```

My router.js start with

```
let router = new Router({
  mode: "history",
  linkExactActiveClass: "exact-active",
  linkActiveClass: "active",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you shouldn't be having multiple `router-view`s in your template. Can you remove those / replace them with the actual components and see if it fixes the issue? Something like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <AppHeader />
  <AppSidebar />
  <main>
  <fade-transition>
    <router-view>
  </fade-transition>
  </main>
</div>
```

If it doesn't, you should post a bit more code of your components and router to help identify the issue.